# Does Text to speech in android studio support Arabic language?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I need to use a speech reader in android studio, there is text in **Arabic Language** in edittext and I need that text to be read using speech reader, what I supposed to do?

Comment: It can.  The plaform it's built on allows different language packs to be installed.  Typically OEMs install them based on the locale the phone will be sold in.  So it's possible but not assured that it will work.  You can use isLanguageAvailable to test if a certain locale is supported on that device.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan  what I supposed to do if the language is not supported?

Comment: Either they need to download support (if available) or you're out of luck.  You could look for a third party library that does it.